# apiKey not working with HERE Reverse Geocoder 6.2 API?

Tags: here-api

Why does the 6.2 Reverse Geocoder API not accept `apiKey` authentication when the documentation says it should?
The result is this:

`<Details>invalid credentials for </Details>`

Comment: Please let us know the exact API call you have used (you can leave your actual ApiKey empty), so we can have a better check.

Comment: [https://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?apiKey=...&maxresults=100&mode=retrieveAddresses&prox=47.2268149,-67.0968282,99]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The endpoint used in your API call is our legacy endpoint, which only work with app_id and app_code. Please use our current endpoint which works with apiKey instead.

https://reverse.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?maxresults=100&mode=retrieveAddresses&prox=47.2268149,-67.0968282,99&apiKey=

Comment: I'm using folium, but I'm getting this error *ValueError at /
Provide app_id & app_code*. How can I get rid of this error? `location = geocoder.here('Winnetka', bbox=bbox, key='...')`

Comment: I solved it by replacing **here** with **osm**. `location = geocoder.here('Winnetka', bbox=bbox, key='...')`to `location = geocoder.osm('Winnetka', bbox=bbox, key='...')`. I had no idea what I were doing, because I were just copying from a tutorial. I realised that I were using **here** which I don't have.

Comment: Now the new apiKey system doesn't work with this endpoint it give me forbidden.