# HERE reverse geocoding API endpoint returns 401

Tags: angular, authentication, here-api, http-status-code-401

I've taken the HERE Reverse geocoding API endpoint from the docs and I can successfully make a GET request in Postman with some random lat/long coords.  This is the endpoint:

*https://revgeocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/revgeocode?at=48.2181679%2C16.3899064&lang=en-US&apiKey=apikey*

However, this does not work in the client.  From my Angular app, I get a 401 http status error.  I've seen answers questions regarding app_id and app_code, but according to HERE's Developer Support's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63215573/apikey-not-working-with-here-reverse-geocoder-6-2-api), api_key has replaced those other parameters at an endpoint that does not work for me neither in my client or Postman.  I do not see anywhere in the HERE project that whitelists domains.  I am passing a valid api_key (obvious).

Answer (score 0):

*https://revgeocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/revgeocode* belongs to HERE Geocoding & Search API v7 service, and it only supports two types of authentication: Bearer and apiKey. If you are still experiencing 401 error with apiKey authentication, then you need to check the request sent from your Angular app and make sure it has the right domain (revgeocode.search.hereapi.com), endpoint, and apiKey.

By the way, for Angular integration, you might use Map JavaScript API? If so, you can follow the below doc to verify your whitelist domain setting:
https://developer.here.com/blog/how-to-whitelist-domain-names